# XSLT date comparison not working

Tags: xslt, date-comparison

I am trying to implement an XSLT date comparison but doesn't seem to work, here is my code:

```
<xsl:variable name="CreatedDate" select="@createDate"/>
                <xsl:variable name="IDAppendedDate" select="2012-01-01" />

                 <b>date: <xsl:value-of select="$CreatedDate"/></b> 

                 <xsl:if test="$CreatedDate > $IDAppendedDate">
                   <h2> mooooooooooooo </h2>
                </xsl:if>
```

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could apply some [XSLT date/time function](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_functions.asp#datetime) to your IDAppendedDate instead of simple string value.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.